# Firefox issue with currentStyle vs getComputedStyle

Tags: javascript, firefox, computed-style

I am trying to get the width of an element according to it's CSS rules  The problem is that "getComputedStyle" returns a pixel value instead of "auto" for an element with no CSS width value set.  In Opera, "elem.currentStyle['width']" returns "auto", but in firefox, it must use "getComputedStyle" which returns something like "1149px".

It is vital for me to know what the actual CSS rule is.  Is there some way of doing this besides besides getComputedStyle? [The Firefox MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/used_value) makes it clear "getComputedStyle" is not the way to go, but I cannot find any documentation for a Firefox equivalent to "currentStyle".

If you want to know, my end goal is to find the largest static-width element on the page. 
 If I cannot read stylesheet values - only rendered/computed values - 
 then how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start with an element, there is no way to know which stylesheet rules applied to it. `getComputedStyle()` merely gives you the effective style value and `currentStyle` isn't much different even though it happens to give you the result you expect in this particular scenario and this particular browser.

What you probably need to do is to go through the stylesheets instead. Along the lines of:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++)
{
  var styleSheet = document.styleSheets[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < styleSheet.cssRules.length; j++)
  {
    var rule = styleSheet.cssRules[j];
    if (rule.type == 1)  // STYLE_RULE
    {
      // Do something with rule.style.width
    }
  }
}
```

If you then need to locate elements matching that rule you can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) with `rule.selectorText`. The remaining problem is that multiple style rules might apply to the same element and the specificity of the rule needs to be calculated. Not sure how much this is a problem for you however.

Additional documentation:

- [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleSheet)
- [CSSStyleRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CSSStyleRule)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid cycling through the stylesheets, as this can be cumbersome from a performance perspective, but I think with some intuition I can make this work.

Comment: P.S. would you know a quick way to find a css rule (without jquery) by class name, without cycling through the stylesheets looking for "className='whatever'"? Ie, is there a "document.getCSSRuleByClass()" or something as such?

Comment: No, I don't think there is anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Unfortunately, as far as I know there is no realistic way to achieve this.</strike>

Edit: The above answer looping through the style sheets is your best bet. I originally thought of accessing the stylesheets but did not think of using querySelectorAll. Hats off to Wladimir for a genius solution.

--

The only solution I could think of is for the elements you're setting a width to, also set some other uncommonly used style to something that won't really affect anything, so you can test for that.

```
div {
    width: 35px;
    min-width: 1px; /* the flag */
    }
```

So then when looking for the elements with a specified width, you can look for [ComputedStyle].minWidth == '1px' first.

Quite a hacky solution but it'll get the job done.

You could also set a random class name to the elements that have a set width, then all you would have to do is query for the elements with that class name. Although it's not a very dynamic solution.

Comment: It's a good idea, but is definitely hacky. I think Wladimir's suggestion of looping through the stylesheets is a little more clean

Answer (score 0):

if you just want get the element's dimension, why not use

`element.clientWidth` or `element.clientHeight`

the getcomputestyle is not designed to retrieve the element's width or height

Comment: The OP wants to find if an element has been defined a width, not just have the computed width.