# How can I get the non computed marginLeft style value of an HTML element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin

I have tried `element.style.marginLeft` but it doesn't work in some inherited style cases (just returns an empty string). Also, `getComputedStyle` is not an option since I want to get "auto" when it is the case instead of the computed value.
For IE, `currentStyle` works for me , but it is not available in other browsers.

I have to use just plain js, **no frameworks**, and I need it to be cross browser.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/7226162/1615483

Comment: for inherited style cases, you may solve your problem using `element.offsetWidth` and make some calculation to find the left margin (subtract the element width and its border size). see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.offsetWidth

Answer (score 1):

use Jquery!

simple sintax:

```
x = #("#idName").css("cssPropertyName");
x = #(".classdName").css("cssPropertyName");
x = #("elementName").css("cssPropertyName");
```

:)